# What should someone look for when selecting a sip registrar?

Tags: voip

Is there any relevant differences between providers that you should look for? Or they are basically all the same and you just choose the one that you like the name more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick "Run-down"**

Cost (per month/per minute), features, connection time, Enhanced 911 Service.

**Long Explanation**

There are many to choose from. One thing to consider, of course, is the costs. The cost of your service should be affordable and worthwhile. For instance, it should have all the features you are looking for, such as call waiting, caller ID, and other such features. It should also give you a plan that works well.

Many VOIP SIP Phone service providers offer several different plans to fit your needs. For example, if you are looking for service now and then, you can choose a plan that offers you a specific rate per minute or a bundle of minutes. Of course, many are now offering unlimited local calling with additional long distance minutes or unlimited calling anywhere within your country as a choice as well.

It is important to choose based on your specific needs and wants in a VOIP service. Compare different companies. Take a look at their rates, their features, and their services. Find out what others are using and what they have to say about any specific company. This is the best way to choose the right service for you and your communication needs.